# How to get TraceId and SpanID from OTEL Tracing

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, otel

I am using SpringBoot and Graphql for a module as well using OTEL. I need spanID and traceID in the logs of the application.

- trace_id: OTel trace trace id, must be present in every log record
  produced in request context.
- span_id: OTel trace span id, must be
  present in every log record produced in request context

In the Query of Subgraph, I tried to write

**System.out.println(Span.current().getSpanContext().getTraceId());**

But getting for every request:

00000000000000000000000000000000

Can anyone tell me what is an appropriate way to generate traceID and SpanID?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the otel javaagent, since it looks like it's disabled.

Comment: Can you perhaps [edit] your answer and explain how to _enable the otel javagent_?